# flink main method does not log

Tags: java, log4j, apache-flink, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 in flink, the strange thing is, the logger does not write to the file in the main method, but it log well in other places.

Example:

```
public class FlinkEntry {

    private static final JedisCluster JEDIS_CLUSTER;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    static {
        Set<HostAndPort> hostAndPorts = new HashSet<>();
        hostAndPorts.add(new HostAndPort("..", 7001));
        JEDIS_CLUSTER = new JedisCluster(hostAndPorts);
        // this line logs ok
        logger.info(JEDIS_CLUSTER.getClusterNodes());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> dataStream = environment.addSource(...);

        SinkFunction<String> redisSink = createRedisSink();
        dataStream.addSink(redisSink).name("redis");

        // this line does not log anything
        logger.info("start to execute"); 
        environment.execute();
    }

    private static SinkFunction<String> createRedisSink() {
        return new SinkFunction<String>() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(String value, Context context) {
                // this line log well
                logger.info("write to redis"); 
                JEDIS_CLUSTER.lpush("rtp:example", value);
                JEDIS_CLUSTER.expire("rtp:example", 10 * 60);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RootAppender" immediateFlush="true" fileName="/tmp/${artifactId}/logs/flinktest.log"
                     filePattern="/tmp/${artifactId}/logs/flink-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}] [%p] - %l - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="RootAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: How do you execute your programm? Submit it using the Flink CLI? Just run it as a standalone programm? Submit it using the Web-CLI?

Comment: Web-CLI. Every thing logs fine except the main method.

Comment: Do you see the output at the logs of the job manager?

Comment: No. I did not see any log in the job manager console...

Comment: @xingbin I have the same problem. Have you figured out the issue why it's not logging in the main method? I'm using Flink CLI to submit job to yarn cluster.